# Official Python documentation error when classifying exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

The [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) states

> There are (at least) two distinguishable kinds of errors: syntax errors and exceptions.

But when looking at the [Exception Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) I see that syntax errors mean  the `SyntaxError` exception is  raised, So there is nothing "special" about it, it is a regular exception like all the other ones, e.g. `RuntimeError`, `ValueError` or `OSError`.

So is the official documentation wrong?

Comment: SyntaxErrors are raised when the code is interpreted, other exceptions are raised during runtime

Comment: @snakecharmerb The answer given so far ("almost nothing special about it") seems to contradict you. Is it a rule that all other exceptions are raised durign runtime? There is no...ahem...exception to this rule?

Comment: I didn't say it was special, I just explained how it was distinct from other exceptions in that it's raised when code is parsed, not when code is executed.  I'm not aware of any other exception raised outside of runtime, but I don't think there's any rule either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's almost nothing special about it. Usually imports throw it so you can even catch it

```
try:
    import xyz
except SyntaxError:
    pass
```

There is however one special behaviour. If the syntax error occures in the main module then you can't intercept it. It is a situation when there is a syntax error in `main.py` and you do `python main.py`.

Comment: +1 this is interesting. So there is no way to catch `SyntaxError` in main, not even by using `sys.excepthook` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) ?

Comment: No, because the code that registers a hook won't execute.